# Menus are being placed below windows' titlebars

Tags: unity, appmenu

I upgraded 12.04 to 14.04 last night. I'm using unity. After upgrade this is what it looks like

[image: menus are being placed below windows titlebar].

> How to place these menus back in global menubar?

I haven't touched any compiz settings.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purge "indicator-appmenu" package & install it again.

Answer (score 0):

In "System Settings > Appearance > Behaviour > Show the menus for a window" there are two options:

- In the menu bar
- In the window's title bar